# Random series whre non are 75% alike

Tags: python, random

So, I've been trying to make a random series generator with the given numbers using an array:
so the possibilities are: [0-9, 0-9, 0-9, 0 - 59, 0-9, 0-9, 0-9].
The only problem is that I want that all the series aren't even 75% the same (no more than 2 numbers the same).
So here are some examples:
Good:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
Not good:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

So, if there are fewer than 2 numbers the same it deletes the second one.
And the second problem is that I want 10,000 of these series.

Sorry if I didn't explain it well, the code would probably explain what I tried to explain.

**TRIGGER WARNING!! CODE ISN'T EFFICIENT AT ALL!!**

```html
TOTAL_SERIES = 10000

placement_amount = [9, 9, 9, 59, 9, 9, 9]

all_series = []

def create_series():
    global fail, success
    series = []

    for i in range(len(placement_amount)):
        series.append(random.randint(0, placement_amount[i]))

    for i in all_series:
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(i)):
            if series[j] == i[j]:
                count += 1
            if count > 2:
                return;

    all_series.append(series)

while len(all_series) < TOTAL_SERIES:
    create_series()
```

The code technically works but it takes around 1 hour to generate 400 of these since the longer it runs the harder it takes to find a series that follows the rules.

So, my question is how do I make it more efficient and so it will make 10,000 series the fastest a code can.

What I've tried so far:
Tried adding cuda so I'll be able to run the code on a gpu making it faster (have python 32-bit so can't)
Tried creating a few threads where each generates 10,000/threads amount and then run a code that deletes all the ones who don't follow the rules (the code just got stuck).

I'm open to hear how I can try these again but with a correct code or anything that will make it efficient.

Comment: How random do you need this? You could simply create 10000 series that you know to be different and reorder them randomly?

Comment: the order of the series doesn't matter all that matters is that I have 10,000 series where they were generated randomly and no 2 series are 75% alike.

Comment: Please remove everything which does not concern creation of the random numbers from the question, and clearly state how to get from your input to your output.

Comment: Btw I don't that think there exist 10,000 such series.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can at most do 5900.

Comment: I removed everything that does not concern the creation and check of the series.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to 5,900 series?

Comment: The first 3 numbers cannot be identical to any previous series by application of your rule. So there are at most 1000 solutions.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I changed it, look at my answer, thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me isn't code efficiency but just that it's impossible make 10,000 series since the first 3 numbers can't be identical, so I changed the lines:

```
if counter > 2:
```

to

```
if counter > 3
```

Thanks everyone for the help, but if you got a way to make it more efficient it would be nice :D

Comment: I'm still not convinced you can make 10000 such series :). Lets reorder you series to [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 59] for simplicity. With C>3 you can have 10000 valid combinations for your first 4 numbers. However as we've used all our rights to reuse digits there are only 10 possibilities for 5th place. So it still doesn't work.

Comment: I see, I'm currently running the program, it made 2,800 series in less than 20 minutes but after that, it made another 1,000 (3,800 in total) after 2 hours of total run time.
I will keep it running for the night and will see at the morning, probably you are right though.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution is in O( P(N)*N), you can reduce it to O(P(N)) with dicts and computing the differrent index combinations:

*-P(N) is the expected number of iterations to get N such series*

*- the constants are larger!*

```
import itertools
import random

indexes=list(itertools.combinations(range(7),3))

big_dict={ k : {}   for k in indexes  }



TOTAL_SERIES = 1000

placement_amount = [9, 9, 9, 59, 9, 9, 9]

all_series = []

loops=0
while len(all_series) < TOTAL_SERIES:
    loops+=1
    candidate = tuple(random.randint(0, amount) for amount in placement_amount)

    if any(   (candidate[index[0]],candidate[index[1]],candidate[index[2]]) in \           
  big_dict[index]  for index in indexes  ):
        continue
    else:
        for index in indexes:
           big_dict[index[(candidate[index[0]],candidate[index[1]],candidate[index[2]])]=True
    all_series.append(candidate)
```

Comment: Note: P(N) seems to be exponential or larger.

Comment: This is really large problem lol, I looped the algorithm a million times and got 370 good series. Furthermore the more you have the less the chance of a finding a valid series.

Answer (score -1):

This must be the solution:

```
import random


def gen_series(pattern):
    return [random.randint(0, max_val) for max_val in pattern]


pattern = [9, 9, 9, 59, 9, 9, 9]

for i in range(100):
    print(gen_series(pattern))
```